# Displaytag in included page

Tags: jsp, struts2, displaytag, jspinclude

I would like to use displaytag in an included page but I have difficulties.
I have got a main page which includes a header jspf, a menu jspf and an other jspf depending on the selected menu (on menu.jspf)

main.jspf

```
<html><body>
<table border="0">
  <tr>
     <td colspan="2"><s:include value="header.jspf"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><s:include value="menu.jspf"/></td>
     <td><s:include value="%{page}"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

the "other" jspf (I change the value of 'page' variable in a Struts2 action)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="display" uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %> 
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/screen.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/displaytag.css" type="text/css"/>
<body>

   <display:table name="${usageList}" pagesize="2" requestURI="menu_admin_freq.action" sort="list" class="mars">
      <display:column property="nameBackendService" title="BackendService" sortable="true"/>
      <display:column property="frequency" title="Frequency" sortable="true"/>
   </display:table>

</body></html>
```

As you can see I include a full JSP page which I think is not a good idea... However when I tried to include only a fragment (without the `<html>` and `<body>` elements) and put the taglib elements into the main.jsp the displaytag table did not appear... When I removed the `<html>` and `<body>` elements and left the taglib one then I could see a text on the webpage : `"<%@ taglib prefix="display" uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" %>"`

At the moment I have got a working solution (by using `<html>`, `<body>` a `<%@ taglib>` elements in the page that must be included) but I think mine is quite a bad design pattern. How should I sort out this?
Thanks,
Viktor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struts2 `<s:include>` tag includes a result of servlet or a JSP page. If you want to include JSP fragments use JSP include directive `<%@ include file="..." %>`.

For using `<s:include>` tag rename your pages to `.jsp` and put only taglib directive (w/o `<html>`, `<body>`) along with your table to the included pages.

Comment: Thanks Aleksandr for the quick response! I need dynamic include and as I know <%@ include is for static include. Am I right? Or do I know incorrectly?thanks,V.

Comment: So just rename your pages to `.jsp` and use `<s:include>` tag.

Comment: Thanks Aleksandr, it works! You were right, all I had to do was to rename to.jsp. V.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
<jsp:include page="mySnippet.jsp"/>
```

where `mySnippet.jsp` is a partial Jsp, with no DTD, no head, no body, and only the HTML fragment you need.

When needed, declare in it the tag-libraries (struts-tags, etc)...

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I had to rename the .jspf to .jsp and it works! Thanks,V.