# Fragment jspf files not correctly included

Tags: jsp, include, jsp-fragments

I moved all my included files into a directory /include from root. Now, when I name those files .jsp they are all included properly:

```
<jsp:include page="/include/default.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

But these files are fragments, thus I want to rename them to .jspf. In this case, the entire content is just printed to the page, it is not properly interpreted by glassfish.

Do I have to register this type?

Thanks a lot for any kind of hint!

Comment: Try to use `<%@ include file="..." %>`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/14707167/1700321.

Comment: aaah, thanks a lot. <jsp:include> is compiled and thus, needs to be an jsp-extension.

Answer (score 0):

For those who come across this question, note that the `*.jspf` convention is not supported by default by all application servers, Tomcat in particular.

The following mapping needs to be added to the application's web.xml in order for jspf to be rendered correctly:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jspf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```